Minimum number of instructions to execute so performance of one processor is higher
An ARM CortexA77 processor has a 13-stage pipeline and a clock frequency of 2.6 GHz.
An ARM Neoverse E1 processor version has a 10-stage pipeline and a clock frequency of  3.1 GHz.
Both processors use a four-issue pipeline.
For a given sequence of instructions, the CortexA77 has an IPC (Instructions Per Cycle) rate of 3. For the same sequence of instructions, the Neoverse E1 has an IPC of 2. Assume that both processors sustain the same IPC rate throughout the execution of the program, i.e. they issue 3 (CortexA77), and 2 (Neoverse E1) instructions per cycle throughout execution.
Assume the two processors execute a sequence of instructions starting with an empty pipeline. What is the minimum number of instructions the two processors need to execute so that the performance of the CortexA77 is higher than that of the Neoverse E1?

Have you tried to write the equations?
